# What does pathelement signify in a buildfile?

Tags: ant

What does `pathelement` signify?

```
<path id="master-classpath">
  <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
  <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
</path>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [path-like structures](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path) in the Ant documentation. A pathelement is part of a path.

If you think of a path as being a list of locations - e.g. directories - you can compose a path out of locations, or shorter paths, or a combination of both:

```
Path X:   a\1:b\2       # Two locations / one path
Path Y:           c\3   # One location / one path
Path XY:  a\1:b\2:c\3   # Three locations / one path
```

A `pathelement` may specify a `path` (i.e. one or more locations), or a single `location`:

```
<path id=X">
  <pathelement path="a\1:b\2"/>
</path>
<path id=Y">
  <pathelement location="c\3"/>
</path>
```